# Does a plugin's "main" file need to be named the same as the folder containing it?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I remember - many moons ago - debugging a plugin that I was building for a very, very, long time. The only thing that fixed my issue (which I can't remember for the life of me), was to name the plugins main file (the one with the plugin header) the exact same name as the plugins folder.

Since then, I have never named the plugin file anything other than the name of the folder. Is this necessary for any core functionality to work, or am I just being superstitious?

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer, NO.

The plugin file can be named anything you want as long as at the very top of it you include the plugin Meta (name, description. ...)

Comment: But if a plugin has several php files, how does Wordpres know which is the "main php file" ? Just by looking for the plugin meta header in all files?

Comment: @leonbloy that is correct.